# Do achievements earned in Windows Phone game trials transfer to the paid version?

Tags: achievements, windows-phone

Some Windows Phone 7 games have limited Xbox Live integration, including Live achievements that add to your Gamerscore. Very commonly (always?), when the game has a trial or demo version, achievements cannot be earned in the demo.

However, when you do something in the trial that would earn you an achievement in the paid game, you'll often be told that achievements only exist in the paid version, and asked if you want to buy the game or keep going with the trial. What I would like to know is:

- If you choose not to buy the game when you earn the achievement, but you buy the game later, will you receive that past trial "achievement" when you do buy the game?
- And what if you do buy the game right away - will you get the achievement then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience with Xbox Live, I've found that if you get an achievement in a trial game, and then unlock the full game in the same session, you'll get credit for your progress and/or achievements.  Most of the time, the game won't save if it's only a trial.  Therefore, exiting out of the game may erase your progress, if the game you're playing doesn't support saving during the trial/demo period.

[Anecdotal evidence](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_live_on_wp7/f/139/t/36533.aspx) seems to support that this works the same way for Windows Phone 7 games that feature Xbox Live achievements.

Comment: Tangential to the question, but when trying to find a reference to support my claim, I stumbled upon [this discussion](http://www.psychologyofgames.com/2010/01/loss-aversion-achievements-and-trial-conversions/) of the psychology of trial games, loss aversion, and unlocking achievements.  It's a rather interesting read, if psychology and video games are interesting to you :)